# Drug Half Life calculator with PHP

Tags: php, math

I have found an excel file online that helps with the calculations of a Drugs Half-life and helps to determine how much of the given drug is likely to remain in ones system based on

- `Hal-life Hour Number`
- `The quantity of the Drug taken per dose`
- `how much is in your system from previous doses`

Below is a screenshot of the Excel file showing both the Output with the calculations already performed and also shows the actual Math that is involved for each day...

- The Columns A, B, C, D, E, etc.. is the Day 24 hours
- Column D Row 6 is the Half life for a Drug in Hours
- From the Image below you can see that the calculation is perfromed and that Value is then used in the Next Day's equation

[image]

---

Ok so I am not that knowledgeable with Math outside of basic Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division I do not know much more then that.

My goal is to create a tool similar to this Excel file but with PHP, I am not sure how to do so but I think all the answers are right here in the image above as far as the math portion.

Looking at `D3` I can see that it takes...

1. `D2`'s value which is `30` in the Image
2. It then Adds `C3`'s value
3. Then Multiplies that by `1/2`
4. I am not sure what the `^` does though?
5. Then it Divides `24 hours` by `D6` which holds the Hour Number

In my PHP I would like to have a Function that I can pass an array of Data, so let's say I pass in an Array with...

- the Number of Days to calculate (my image shows like 4 days so if I pass 10 days, it will shows the daily results up to 10 days)
- Then an array of the Daily amount consumed in mg (so in my image this would be an array with `30`,`0`,`30`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`
- Then I would also pass in the Half Life in Hours, so in my image the drug used has a half-life of 4.5 hours

This function would then return an array with the data for each day, should show the remaining mg in one's system for each day, I can then use this data result to build charts, graphs, or simply a List

I would appreciate any help to get me started, I think I can pull this off on my own but I need help getting the math portion 100%, above I break down the equation as I see it, please help me understand better for example I am not sure what `^` does in the equation or how to do it in PHP

I hope my question is not too vague, I will come back with more specific once I get a good start on this but please help if you can so far, thank you for reading.

Comment: `^` = Exponentiation Other than that, what php code do you have so far?

Comment: The caret is for exponentiation: 2^2 = 4 (2 squared) or 2^3 = 8 (2 cubed)

Comment: The `^` raises the left hand side to the power of the right hand side.

Comment: The Half-Life of anything is the amount of time it takes for the stuff to halve in value. Just a FYI, but not all drugs have a zeroth-order halflife. Many have much more complicated halflives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_law

Comment: Use PHP's `pow` function for the exponentiation. It sounds like you have a pretty good handle on the rest.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, the equation will probably make more sense if you know more about what exactly half life means: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calcHalfLife( $mgTaken , $drugHalfLifeHours , $day ) {
    //total number of half-lifes elapsed
    $total_half_lifes = ($day * 24) / $drugHalfLifeHours;
    //total reduction in dosage
    $reductionFactor = pow( 0.5 , $total_half_lifes );
    //return the current dosage in the person's system
    return round( $mgTaken * $reductionFactor , 2 );
}
```

The above function should do the trick. Pass in the MG dosage taken, the number of hours for that drug's half-life, and the number of days since the dosage.

The function calculates the number of half-lifes experienced by the drug by taking the number of days * 24 hours in a day and dividing that by the total number of hours it takes for a half-life of that drug. This is the number of times the drug's dosage would be cut in half.

It then takes 0.5 (50% as a decimal) and increments it to the power of the total number of half lifes experienced by the drug. So 1 half life would be 0.5, 2 would be 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 etc etc. This is the decimal representation of the percentage of the drug left in the person's system.

It then multiplies that remainder by the original amount taken and rounds it off to 2 decimal places. The return floating point value will be a representation of the remaining MG dosage of the drug in the person's system.

If you're looking to build a function/system that allows you to calculate a daily dosage of that drug (ie: the person takes the same dosage each day as opposed to once) that is a very different formula and function, but the basic principle is the same as the one I wrote for you here.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start, I do want to figure out the combined amount based on taking a certain amount daily or even different amounts on different days.  After playing with this some it looks like this is a good starting point to create that as this function can be used inside my other function so thanks this is great

Comment: I am thinking I can have another function where I pass in an array with the Day and amount taken for that day, then iterate that array and run your function on those values for each day.  So I would run this and then Add the result from the previous day to the MG taken for that day and run it again.  So if on day 1 I took 30mg and day 2 took 20mg, I would get 0.74409424 for day 1 and add Day 2's 20mg to that and then run that amount through your function to get Day 2's actual ammount (hopefully I said that right but I do have it right in my head)

Comment: That would work, yes. If you intended to take the same amount each day, you could actually just modify the function slightly and have it use a loop instead of the pow() function. I would initialize an array before the loop and push each day's result into that array. The end result would be an output array with the dosage in the person's system for each day. Obviously you'd need to add an input value to tell the function how many days you want to run the data for. Anyway good luck to ya ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up doing it with an Array passed into another function, that way I can have different dosage for each day, also when detoxing I can put 0 for certain days.  http://www.codedevelopr.com/php-drug-half-life-calculator/

Comment: Online half life elimination tool: http://www.subotex.com/suboxone-taper-chart-blood-plasma-levels/ this is the best online tool I've found for finding a taper you can use it for any drug just set the half life for the drug you are graphing.